# Applying filters efficiently by considering multiple column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table of data that has been extracted from a large table using MS SQL. I am trying to have my final result with just one SubmissionNo per policy. I am looking to apply filters with below conditions. Any help/thoughts will be much appreciated!

Condition 1:  When **Country = US**, and **Office='only US locations'**  then no filters would be applied.

Condition 2: when there are multiple rows of the same submission number, then I need to check if **Country = US and some other country**(e.g ID's 3 and 5th record), then go to "Office" and select the **ID** for that Office.

condition 3: For **any Non-US country** with just one row, pick up the same row to the final result.

Query:

select *from Table1 where

***Table***

```
+---+------------+-------------+-----------------+
|ID |    Office  | Country     | SubmissionNo    |
+---+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1 | Toronto    | Canada      |  0121-01        | 
| 2 | Atlanta    | US          |  0121-02        |   
| 6 | Atlanta    | US          |  0121-04        |    
| 3 | Toronto    | Canada      |  0121-032       |   
| 5 | Toronto    | US          |  0121-032       |   
| 9 | New York   | Canada      |  0121-05        |   
| 8 | New York   | US          |  0121-05        |   
+---+------------+-------------+---------------- +
```

***Expected Results***

```
+---+------------+-------------+-----------------+
|ID |    Office  | Country     | SubmissionNo    |
+---+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1 | Toronto    | Canada      |  0121-01        | 
| 2 | Atlanta    | US          |  0121-02        |   
| 6 | Atlanta    | US          |  0121-04        |    
| 3 | Toronto    | Canada      |  0121-032       |      
| 8 | New York   | US          |  0121-05        |   
+---+------------+-------------+---------------- +
```

Comment: Please, give more detail. Your explanation is little bit confused. For example, paste the OfficeTable wit Id, and give Expected results for each Condition

Comment: Now I'm thinking, is this question really unclear or  this is just my english issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do quite a bit in your situation with group by, aggregate functions like count and sub queries.  The way you've phrased the rules may be correct, but isn't very SQL friendly.  For example, how would a query know which Office values are located in the US?

```
select
from Table1 T1
join
(
select SubmissionNo,count(*)
from Table1
group by SubmissionNo
) T2
on T1.SubmissionNumber = T2.SubmissionNumber.
```